# Assigning students in groups

Tags: random-matrices

I have a project with 60 students and 6 teachers. I'd like to know if I can use Sage or Mathematica to assign those 60 students in 6 groups. There would be 6 sessions (a month each). Each student has to work once with each teacher and avoid being in the same group of students (as much as possible).
Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll need to quantify "as much as possible". If you required that a student may not be in a group with the same other student twice, this would be the social golfer problem; but that's impossible since there are more students per group than groups.

Comment: It's ok if two students of a new group were in the same group before. I only need that it doesn't happen with the same two students everytime.